# How can I make "i" from a main loop reflect the times that an inner loop inside that main loop runs

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout

I am running a for loop that will call `typeDelay(i)`

This function  will be typing characters one by one on each iteration.

Inside `typeDelay(i)`, when the two first `IF` statement inside `setTimeout` are met (the length of the text that I am typing is equal to 52 and it is not an empty space), I want to know when I will hit an empty space by starting a loop that types characters, and stopping it when I get to an empty space.

For this iteration I need to increase `i` so that each time I type the next character.

The problem is that on this iteration I am going to be increasing the `i` that belongs to the `typeDelay()` function and not the one that belongs to the main loop that called `typeDelay(i)`, which I need to do because every character that is added inside this inner loop does not need to be added from the main loop.

When I go back to the original loop, the `i` belonging to this main loop is still going to have the value that it had before the two `IF` statement inside `typeDelay(i)` were met.

And I want this `i` belonging to the main loop to also reflect the times that the inner loop inside `typeDelay(i)` ran.

How can I make the `i` in the main loop to reflect the times that the loop inside typeDelay(i) ran.

```
function typeDelay(i) {

    setTimeout(() => {

        newText += placeRelationStatus.charAt(i);
        typedTextParagraph.innerHTML = typedTextParagraph.innerHTML + placeRelationStatus.charAt(i);

        
        if (typedTextParagraph.innerHTML.length === 52) {

            if (typedTextParagraph.innerHTML.charAt(typedTextParagraph.innerHTML.length - 1) != " ") {
                let difference = placeRelationStatus.length - newText.length;

                i = i + 1
                

                // INNER LOOP:

                for (let iter = 0; iter < difference; iter++) {

                    typedTextParagraph.innerHTML = typedTextParagraph.innerHTML + placeRelationStatus.charAt(i);

                    if (typedTextParagraph.innerHTML.charAt(typedTextParagraph.innerHTML.length - 1) === " ") {

                        typedTextParagraph.innerHTML = typedTextParagraph.innerHTML + "<br>";

                        break;

                    }

                    i++;
                }
            }
            else {
                typedTextParagraph.innerHTML = typedTextParagraph.innerHTML + "<br>"; // I the last character of "typedTextParagraph.innerHTML" is 52 but not equal to an empty space, then we'll just add '<br>' to "typedTextParagraph.innerHTML"
            }
        }


        if (placeRelationStatus === newText) {


            resolve(currentLabel);

        } else {

            return typedTextParagraph.innerHTML

        }

    }, 50 * i);

}

 //MAIN LOOP:

for (i; i < placeRelationStatus.length; i++) {
    
    typeDelay(i)

}
```

Let me know if there is a better way to accomplish this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably simplest would be to return a value from the typeDelay() function and add to i.

```
for (i; i < placeRelationStatus.length; i++) {
    
    i += typeDelay(i)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a much more clean code:

```
                    function typeDelay(u, c) {

                                setTimeout(() => {
                                 placeRelationStatus.charAt(u);
                                    typedTextParagraph.innerHTML = typedTextParagraph.innerHTML + placeRelationStatus.charAt(u);

                                    if (placeRelationStatus === newText) {
                                        resolve(currentLabel);
                                    }
                                    
                                    u++;
                                    newText += typedTextParagraph.innerHTML
                                    typeChars(typedTextParagraph.innerHTML.length, u++, c);

                                }, 50);

                            }


                    function typeChars(i, u, c) {

                                if (i < 52 * c) {
                                    typeDelay(u, c);
                                } else if (i >= 52 * c && typedTextParagraph.innerHTML.charAt(typedTextParagraph.innerHTML.length - 1) != " ") {
                                    typeDelay(u, c);
                                } else if (i >= 52 * c && typedTextParagraph.innerHTML.charAt(typedTextParagraph.innerHTML.length - 1) === " ") {
                                    typedTextParagraph.innerHTML += "<br>";
                                    c++
                                    typeDelay(u, c);
                                }
                            }

                    typeChars(typedTextParagraph.innerHTML.length, 0, 1);
```